# How to identify right CPU limit for a pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

In the context of an Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) environment, I currently manage a development cluster of modest scale, which differs in size from our production cluster. When determining the CPU resource allocation for a given pod, if my development cluster necessitates 1000 milliCPU (mCPU), should I maintain an equivalent CPU allocation for my production cluster? Is 1000mCPU a consistent metric across different cluster sizes?

Upon reviewing several informational resources, it has come to my attention that CPU allocation is fundamentally tied to the total CPU time that a pod is granted. However, it is important to consider that a more powerful underlying machine can process a greater volume of work within the same unit of time. Can I safely assume that my interpretation of this concept is accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Various things can influence the resource consumption of your workload between environments.
As you mentioned, one of them is the underlying used machine flavor.
In addition, application context may influence too, e.g. type of data, amount of analyzed data, etc.
Moreover, the number of pods running on each node may differ and cause more/less CPU context swiches, throttling, and influence the amount of consumed CPU by your workload.

I would suggest a data-driven approach to deal with that challenge.
You can utilize tools such as [vpa](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/vertical-pod-autoscaler.html) or [krr](https://github.com/robusta-dev/krr) regularly to right-size the resources, request & limit that suits your strategy, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> should I maintain an equivalent CPU allocation for my production cluster?

You should do that if you need some testing results that are similar to the production cluster such as running performance testing against services on the development cluster to ensure the workload before promoting to production.

> Is 1000mCPU a consistent metric across different cluster sizes?

No, it is, because a machine with a higher CPU frequency can process more tasks than the lower one.

**;tldr;**

Kubernetes CPU limit is regarding the CPU time, it uses CFS Bandwidth Control on the Linux kernel to manage them through 2 parameters (cfs_peroid_ms, cfs_quota_ms)

the `cfs_period_us` is [set to 100ms (100k microseconds) by default](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/)

the `cfs_quota_us` comes from a user through the CPU limit value.

So, if you set a CPU limit to 1000m means 1 vCPU or 1,000 millicores (m) = 100,000 microseconds (us) = 100 milliseconds (ms)

If an app runs a task beyond 100ms, it'll be throttled, meaning increased latency.

You can query cAdvisor metrics e.g. `container_cpu_cfs_throttled_periods_total`, `container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total`, `container_cpu_cfs_periods_total`. to see the throttling.

So, let's increase the CPU limit when you query the metrics and experience the throttling issue.

References

- https://danishpraka.sh/posts/kubernetes-and-cpu-limits/
- [Multi threading with Millicores in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61851751/multi-threading-with-millicores-in-kubernetes)

I hope this answer may help you.

Comment: I guess you mean 100,000 µs and not 10k in the example.

Comment: One doubt a powerful machine can do much more in 100,000 us then shouldn't this be different for different powered machines?

Comment: IMO, It should be different because a machine with a higher CPU frequency can do more in 100,000 us.

Comment: Yup that why I raised the question to understand this better and get a concrete answer on this. Because with this 1000m will be different on different cluster sizes.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I already edited the answer for more accuracy. Thanks :)